# How to get the frame of a UIView that has been setup through snapkit

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

First off, I really want to thank the guys who have built snapkit. It has really made setting up constraints for UIViews really easy.

But for now, I have a simple question: How can I access the frame property of a view I setup using this library?

For example:

```
self.view.addSubview(contributePosterView)
self.contributePosterView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp.left)
    make.width.equalTo(self.view.bounds.width)
    make.top.equalTo(self.table.snp.bottom)
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.snp.bottom)
}
```

How can I access the frame property of the view which I have named as `contributePosterView`?

This is important to me especially when I have to set them up in a `UIScrollview` using layoutSubviews property of the said scroll view.

I checked the snapkit documentation as much as I could but still have not found an answer.

How should I go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to access `frame`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need it to get the dimensions of the said UIView in order to determine the correct content size for my scroll view

Comment: Never used snapkit, but for any view, you can get the correct `frame` if you have implemented `layoutSubviews` inside that view's parent.

Comment: @PavanVasan - if you're using auto-layout correctly, you shouldn't need to set the `.contentSize` of your scroll view... it's set automatically. If you really need to get the size of `contributePosterView`, you can get it with `contributePosterView.frame`. Note, however, that the frame will not be set until after auto-layout has completed its work. Generally, the frame will be valid in `didLayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: @DonMag: is it viewDidLayoutSubviews() that you are implying?

Comment: @PavanVasan - yep, sorry... typing without looking closely :)

Comment: @DonMag: Thanks for the clarification. checking it out now.

Comment: @DonMag: It worked. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @PavanVasan - I added this as an answer, for the benefit of other folks who may come across it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"SnapKit" provides methods to add constraints, using a syntax that many people find easier than the default `NSLayoutContraint` methods. However, it doesn't do anything to the views to make it impossible to get the resulting frames sizes.

The issue is that you are likely making your "snap" calls in `viewDidLoad()`, and then immediately trying to get the frame. At that point, all that has happened is that the constraints have been added, but auto-layout has not done its work.

You want to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, at which point you can get the valid frame size:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // now you can get the resulting frame
    let f = self.contributePosterView.frame

   // do what you want with the frame
}
```